# Search on two fields in MongoDB are incredibly slow comparing to one field search

Tags: mongodb, performance, indexing

I'm new to MongoDB, trying to setup 1 node with rather big database. 1 billion rows, 140GB, 10 fields. All fields except one will have separate indexes, because we plan many different queries, which will combine 2 or 3 fields.

My problem is that MongoDB seems not to use separate indexes on combined search.

```
db.alldata.find({ p: "степанович" })
```

this search answers less than 1 second.

```
db.alldata.find({ n: "иван" })
```

this one also.

But db.alldata.find({ n: "иван", p: "степанович" })

takes forever to complete. Am I doing something wrong?
I do not want to use combined indexes because we have too many different queries and even separate indexes take almost all RAM (50GB)

Indexes **are** created. And there **is** enough RAM to fit them.
OS is CentOS7, FS is xfs (if it matters).

UPDATE:

```
db.alldata.find({ n: "иван", p: "степанович"}).explain("allPlansExecution")

{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "myDb.alldata",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                        "$and" : [
                                {
                                        "n" : {
                                                "$eq" : "иван"
                                        }
                                },
                                {
                                        "p" : {
                                                "$eq" : "степанович"
                                        }
                                }
                        ]
                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "filter" : {
                                "n" : {
                                        "$eq" : "иван"
                                }
                        },
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                "keyPattern" : {
                                        "p" : 1
                                },
                                "indexName" : "parentalName",
                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                "isUnique" : false,
                                "isSparse" : false,
                                "isPartial" : false,
                                "indexVersion" : 1,
                                "direction" : "forward",
                                "indexBounds" : {
                                        "p" : [
                                                "[\"степанович\", \"степанович\"]"
                                        ]
                                }
                        }
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [
                        {
                                "stage" : "FETCH",
                                "filter" : {
                  "p" : {
                                                "$eq" : "степанович"
                                        }
                                },
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                        "keyPattern" : {
                                                "n" : 1
                                        },
                                        "indexName" : "firstName",
                                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                                        "isUnique" : false,
                                        "isSparse" : false,
                                        "isPartial" : false,
                                        "indexVersion" : 1,
                                        "direction" : "forward",
                                        "indexBounds" : {
                                                "n" : [
                                                        "[\"иван\", \"иван\"]"
                                                ]
                                        }
                                }
                        },
                        {
                                "stage" : "FETCH",
                                "filter" : {
                                        "$and" : [
                                                {
                                                        "n" : {
                                                                "$eq" : "иван"
                                                        }
                                                },
                                                {
          "p" : {
                                                                "$eq" : "степанович"
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        ]
                                },
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "AND_SORTED",
                                        "inputStages" : [
                                                {
                                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                        "keyPattern" : {
                                                                "n" : 1
                                                        },
                                                        "indexName" : "firstName",
                                                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                                                        "isUnique" : false,
                                                        "isSparse" : false,
                                                        "isPartial" : false,
                                                        "indexVersion" : 1,
                                                        "direction" : "forward",
                                                        "indexBounds" : {
                                                                "n" : [
                                                                        "[\"иван\", \"иван\"]"
                                                                ]
                                                        }
                                                },
                                                {
                                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                        "keyPattern" : {
                                                                "p" : 1
                                                        },
                                                        "indexName" : "parentalName",
                                                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                                                        "isUnique" : false,
                                                        "isSparse" : false,
                                                        "isPartial" : false,
                                                        "indexVersion" : 1,
                                                        "direction" : "forward",
                                                        "indexBounds" : {
                                                                "p" : [
                                                                        "[\"степанович\", \"степанович\"]"
                                                                ]
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        ]
                                }
                        }
                ]
        },
        "executionStats" : {
                "executionSuccess" : true,
                "nReturned" : 31,
                "executionTimeMillis" : 213504,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 124244,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 124244,
                "executionStages" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "filter" : {
                                "n" : {
                                        "$eq" : "иван"
                                }
                        },
                        "nReturned" : 31,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 13160,
                      "works" : 124246,
                        "advanced" : 31,
                        "needTime" : 124213,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 11965,
                        "restoreState" : 11965,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "docsExamined" : 124244,
                        "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                "nReturned" : 124244,
                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 240,
                                "works" : 124245,
                                "advanced" : 124244,
                                "needTime" : 0,
                                "needYield" : 0,
                                "saveState" : 11965,
                                "restoreState" : 11965,
                                "isEOF" : 1,
                                "invalidates" : 0,
                                "keyPattern" : {
                                        "p" : 1
                                },
                                "indexName" : "parentalName",
                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                "isUnique" : false,
                                "isSparse" : false,
                                "isPartial" : false,
                                "indexVersion" : 1,
                                "direction" : "forward",
                                "indexBounds" : {
                                        "p" : [
                                                "[\"степанович\", \"степанович\"]"
                                        ]
                                },
                                "keysExamined" : 124244,
                                "dupsTested" : 0,
                                "dupsDropped" : 0,
                                "seenInvalidated" : 0
                        }
                },
                "allPlansExecution" : [
                        {
                                "nReturned" : 18,
                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 196410,
                                "totalKeysExamined" : 124245,
                                "totalDocsExamined" : 124245,
                                "executionStages" : {
                                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                                        "filter" : {
                                                "p" : {
                                                        "$eq" : "степанович"
                                                }
                                        },
                                        "nReturned" : 18,
                                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 196410,
                                        "works" : 124245,
                                        "advanced" : 18,
                                        "needTime" : 124227,
                                        "needYield" : 0,
                                        "saveState" : 11965,
                                        "restoreState" : 11965,
                                  "isEOF" : 0,
                                        "invalidates" : 0,
                                        "docsExamined" : 124245,
                                        "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                                        "inputStage" : {
                                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                "nReturned" : 124245,
                                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 240,
                                                "works" : 124245,
                                                "advanced" : 124245,
                                                "needTime" : 0,
                                                "needYield" : 0,
                                                "saveState" : 11965,
                                                "restoreState" : 11965,
                                                "isEOF" : 0,
                                                "invalidates" : 0,
                                                "keyPattern" : {
                                                        "n" : 1
                                                },
                                                "indexName" : "firstName",
                                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                                "isUnique" : false,
                                                "isSparse" : false,
                                                "isPartial" : false,
                                                "indexVersion" : 1,
                                                "direction" : "forward",
                                                "indexBounds" : {
                                                        "n" : [
                                                                "[\"иван\", \"иван\"]"
                                                        ]
                                                },
                                                "keysExamined" : 124245,
                                                "dupsTested" : 0,
                                                "dupsDropped" : 0,
                                                "seenInvalidated" : 0
                                        }
                                }
                        },
                        {
                                "nReturned" : 13,
                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 540,
                                "totalKeysExamined" : 124245,
                                "totalDocsExamined" : 13,
                                "executionStages" : {
                                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                                        "filter" : {
                                                "$and" : [
                                                        {
                                                                "n" : {
                                                                        "$eq" : "иван"
                                                                }
                                                        },
                                                        {
                                                                "p" : {
                                                                        "$eq" : "степанович"
                                                                }
                                                        }
                                                ]
                                        },
                                        "nReturned" : 13,
                                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 540,
                                        "works" : 124245,
                                        "advanced" : 13,
                                        "needTime" : 124232,
                                      "needYield" : 0,
                                        "saveState" : 11965,
                                        "restoreState" : 11965,
                                        "isEOF" : 0,
                                        "invalidates" : 0,
                                        "docsExamined" : 13,
                                        "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                                        "inputStage" : {
                                                "stage" : "AND_SORTED",
                                                "nReturned" : 13,
                                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 490,
                                                "works" : 124245,
                                                "advanced" : 13,
                                                "needTime" : 124232,
                                                "needYield" : 0,
                                                "saveState" : 11965,
                                                "restoreState" : 11965,
                                                "isEOF" : 0,
                                                "invalidates" : 0,
                                                "flagged" : 0,
                                                "failedAnd_0" : 29865,
                                                "failedAnd_1" : 29858,
                                                "inputStages" : [
                                                        {
                                                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                                "nReturned" : 74468,
                                                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 250,
                                                                "works" : 74468,
                                                                "advanced" : 74468,
                                                                "needTime" : 0,
                                                                "needYield" : 0,
                                                                "saveState" : 11965,
                                                                "restoreState" : 11965,
                                                                "isEOF" : 0,
                                                                "invalidates" : 0,
                                                                "keyPattern" : {
                                                                        "n" : 1
                                                                },
                                                                "indexName" : "firstName",
                                                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                                                "isUnique" : false,
                                                                "isSparse" : false,
                                                                "isPartial" : false,
                                                                "indexVersion" : 1,
                                                                "direction" : "forward",
                                                                "indexBounds" : {
                                                                        "n" : [
                                                                                "[\"иван\", \"иван\"]"
                                                                        ]
                                                                },
                                                                "keysExamined" : 74468,
                                                                "dupsTested" : 0,
                                                                "dupsDropped" : 0,
                                                                "seenInvalidated" : 0
                                                        },
                                                        {
                                                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                                "nReturned" : 49777,
                                                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 150,
                                                                "works" : 49777,
                                                                "advanced" : 49777,
                                                                "needTime" : 0,
                                                                "needYield" : 0,
                                                                "saveState" : 11965,
                                                                "restoreState" : 11965,
                                                                "isEOF" : 0,
                                                                "invalidates" : 0,
                                                                "keyPattern" : {
                                                                        "p" : 1
                                                                },
                                                                "indexName" : "parentalName",
                                                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                                                "isUnique" : false,
                                                                "isSparse" : false,
                                                                "isPartial" : false,
                                                                "indexVersion" : 1,
                                                                "direction" : "forward",
                                                                "indexBounds" : {
                                                                        "p" : [
                                                                                "[\"степанович\", \"степанович\"]"
                                                                        ]
                                                                },
                                                                "keysExamined" : 49777,
                                                                "dupsTested" : 0,
                                                                "dupsDropped" : 0,
                                                                "seenInvalidated" : 0
                                                        }
                                                ]
                                        }
                                }
                        },
                        {
                                "nReturned" : 31,
                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 13160,
                                "totalKeysExamined" : 124244,
                                "totalDocsExamined" : 124244,
                                "executionStages" : {
                                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                                        "filter" : {
                                                "n" : {
                                                        "$eq" : "иван"
                                                }
                                        },
                                        "nReturned" : 31,
                                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 13160,
                                        "works" : 124245,
                                        "advanced" : 31,
                                        "needTime" : 124213,
                                        "needYield" : 0,
                                        "saveState" : 11965,
                                        "restoreState" : 11965,
                                        "isEOF" : 1,
                                        "invalidates" : 0,
                                        "docsExamined" : 124244,
                                        "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                                        "inputStage" : {
                                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                "nReturned" : 124244,
                                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 240,
                                                "works" : 124245,
                                                "advanced" : 124244,
                                                "needTime" : 0,
                                                "needYield" : 0,
                                                "saveState" : 11965,
                                                "restoreState" : 11965,
                                                "isEOF" : 1,
                                                "invalidates" : 0,
                                                "keyPattern" : {
                           "p" : 1
                                                },
                                                "indexName" : "parentalName",
                                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                                "isUnique" : false,
                                                "isSparse" : false,
                                                "isPartial" : false,
                                                "indexVersion" : 1,
                                                "direction" : "forward",
                                                "indexBounds" : {
                                                        "p" : [
                                                                "[\"степанович\", \"степанович\"]"
                                                        ]
                                                },
                                                "keysExamined" : 124244,
                                                "dupsTested" : 0,
                                                "dupsDropped" : 0,
                                                "seenInvalidated" : 0
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                ]
        },
        "serverInfo" : {
                "host" : "cass",
                "port" : 27017,
                "version" : "3.2.4",
                "gitVersion" : "e2ee9ffcf9f5a94fad76802e28cc978718bb7a30"
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Please update your post with explain result. `db.alldata.find({ n: "иван", p: "степанович" }).explain("allPlansExecution ")`. Also please mention your MongoDB version and if you are using mmap or wiredtiger engine.

Comment: "3.2.4" from official repo and wiredTiger. Added allPlansExecution.

Comment: Thank you. Please send me output from  `collection.getIndexes()` too.

Comment: Making compound indexes was a waste of time. Nothing changed and compound index on 3 fields was 32GB, while 3 separate indexes only took 17. Now rebuilding separate indexes back (this takes about 10 hours in foreground) and will experiment with hints.

Comment: DB is described in the question. 10 fields and each take 7-10GBs, so I cannot afford composite indexes. They will not fit in RAM.

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is that MongoDB seems not to use separate indexes on
>   combined search.

After MongoDb 2.6, MongoDb supports [Index Intersection](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-intersection/)

But you should use combine indexes if you need. Because [prefixes](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/#prefixes) can be very handle.

Even with indexes, queries are very important. So you should use your queries based on [Create Queries that Ensure Selectivity](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-queries-that-ensure-selectivity/). Therefore you should select which index will be used or no index will be used for your query with [hint()](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.hint/).

After you understand this concepts you can [measure your indexes](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/measure-index-use/#indexes-measuring-use) and decide best for your expectation.

Comment: Unbelievable, but it didn't help. I do db.alldata.find(blabla).hint("surname","firstname") and query works for minutes. In my 1 billion of rows of course I have many non-unique values. I cannot change this.

Comment: Interesting. MongoDB allows to specify a hint with two indexes by name, but doesn't actually use the second. And not allows to set second index in hint by column name. So, probably, I must use compound indexes as well.

Comment: What's your moongodb version?

Comment: "version" : "3.2.4",
                "gitVersion" : "e2ee9ffcf9f5a94fad76802e28cc978718bb7a30"